# Can a short circuit kill the USB port of a PC?

Tags: usb, hobbyist

I use a cut USB cable as a 5V power supply from my laptop.

If the two wires on the other side happen to touch each other, will it kill my USB port?

Just to be cautious.

Comment: Depends how well designed the laptop is.

Comment: @Finbarr is correct.  The USB spec requires USB ports to hold up to a short circuit, and some do better than others.  Some manufacturers meet the minimums and no more.  Some go above and beyond.  Then there are those that don't care about the specs, just finding enough suckers to gamble on the lower cost option to make a profit.

Comment: I learned this the hard way, on an Asus Zenbook UX303 using a [magnetic USB cable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8P6Q3.png) which short-circuited when touching the metal case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It could, depending on how it is built, and how you will short it.

If simply shorting 5V to GND, it could survive many events. Shorting 5V to data pins can damage the data pins. Shorting 5V to some other higher voltage in the circuit can damage the whole laptop.

If you like to have working USB ports and laptops, don't use your laptop as a power supply.

Comment: Loved the last line. Hehe.

Comment: From USB ECN: "A USB transceiver is recommended, but not required, to withstand a continuous short of D+ and/or D- to VBUS for a minimum of 24 hours without degradation". So "can" probably should be changed to "might" for technical accuracy :-)

Comment: @Ale..chenski interestingly, at one point it was required, but then they removed that from the standard (not sure why exactly, it seems like a reasonable requirement)

Answer (score 3):

Many USB controllers will shut down the port if it uses too much current.  This affords a modicum of protection, but that's no sure thing.

A powered hub is a cheap insurance policy.

Answer (score 1):

I think you did more than just short it. USB ports have current limit built into them to prevent overloading. Most computer USB ports supply 5V of electricity with a maximum current of 0.5A. This amount of current is standard across the majority of computers and means the overall power output will be 2.5 Watts at best. Later USB designs bring that current up to 0.9A. TI has a nice article on "Powering electronics from the USB port". It is about 8 pages long. It gives you voltages, current etc. unique requirement of the USB power interface is the different current draws allowed. It explains that when a device is first connected to the USB, its bypass capacitor could be charged abruptly and create a glitch on the host equipment supply. The USB specification resolves this problem by limiting the initial power surge in two ways. The peripheral device is allowed only a small (<10-μF) bypass capacitor,and the charge drawn from the bus is limited to 50 μC over a specified time. Larger capacitors can be used if inrush limiting is provided. The article by Robert Kollman and John Bettern goes into all the details of how the ports actually work and what is allowed and what is not.

Comment: " Most computer USB ports supply 5V of electricity with a maximum current of 0.5A. "  That has not been true even in the days of USB 1.1.  The ability to provide 1.5A from a USB port is common in order to meet the USB-BC spec published in 2012.  3A minimum from USB ports is part of a number of specs, USB 3.2, USB-C, and USB-PD.  There are maximums for current draw in the spec but that does not mean the port will supply only that much current and no more, fuses on USB ports are not precision made parts and they will supply the max draw allowed plus some margin before cutting power.